# Unusual ActiveRecord Behavior

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm encountering an unexpected situation with finding/creating particular records in the following table during periods of high contention. I believe there is a race condition in the database.

```
  create_table "business_objects", force: :cascade do |t| 
    t.string   "obj_id",     limit: 255 
    t.string   "obj_type",   limit: 255 
    t.datetime "created_at",             precision: 6, null: false
  end 

  add_index "business_objects", ["obj_type", "obj_id"], name: "index_business_objects_on_obj_type_and_obj_id", unique: true, using: :btree
```

Offending code:

```
def find_or_create_this
 attributes = self.attributes.slice('obj_id', 'obj_type')
 BusinessObject.find_or_create_by!(attributes) 
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique
  BusinessObject.find_by!(attributes)
end
```

The find in the `find_or_create_by!` returns nil and triggers the `create!` which raises a `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique` error.  The rescue block catches it and attempts to find the record which caused the not unique error but it also returns nil.  My expectation is that if the index uniqueness constraint is violated than the record should be committed to the table. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, research the Transaction Isolation Level for [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html).  Wrap the offending code in a transaction block and modify the the isolation level.

The options are:

1. READ UNCOMMITTED
2. SERIALIZABLE
3. REPEATABLE READ
4. READ COMMITTED

   `def find_or_create_this
     attributes = self.attributes.slice('obj_id', 'obj_type')
     ActiveRecord::Base.transaction(isolation: :read_committed) do
       BusinessObject.find_or_create_by!(attributes) 
     end
   rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique
     ActiveRecord::Base.transaction(isolation: :read_committed) do
       BusinessObject.find_by!(attributes)
     end
   end`